# How to center text with image in P tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the text to the center of the photo. However the image is wrapped around a P tag. Any ideas on how to center this?

The problem:
[image]

What I want:

[image]

Code:

HTML:

```
 <div class="customerreviewcontent">
      <div><em>"Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a <br> startup which leaves me with no time for <br> cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now <br> that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!"</em> 
        <p ><img src="resources/css/img/customer-1.jpg" style="border-radius: 15px; height: 40px;"  alt=""> Albert Duncon</p>
      </div>

      <div><em>"Inexpensive, healthy and great-tasting meals,<br> delivered right to my home. We have lots <br>of food delivery here in Lisbon, but no one <br> comes even close to Omifood. Me and my <br> family are so in love!"</em>
      <p> <img src="resources/css/img/customer-2.jpg" style="border-radius: 15px; height: 40px;" alt=""> Joana Silva</p>
      </div>
      <div><em>"I was looking for a quick and easy food <br> delivery service in San Franciso. I tried a lot <br> of them and ended up with Omnifood. Best food delivery service in the Bay Area.<br> Keep up the great work!"</em>
      <p><img src="resources/css/img/customer-3.jpg" style="border-radius: 15px; height: 40px;" alt="">Milton Chapman</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have image inside p tag? use a span maybe; also not clear what you want output as

Comment: In other words, I basically want the text to be moved up so it sits in the center next to the photo.

Answer (score 3):

add `vertical-align: middle;` on image

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.  This will work.
Add a **<div>** tag and set this styles
**display:flex;**
**align-items: center;**

```html
<div class="customerreviewcontent">
      <div><em>"Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a <br> startup which leaves me with no time for <br> cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now <br> that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!"</em> 
        <p><div style="display:flex;align-items: center;"><img src="resources/css/img/customer-1.jpg" style="border-radius: 15px; height: 40px;"  alt=""> Albert Duncon</div></p>
      </div>

      <div><em>"Inexpensive, healthy and great-tasting meals,<br> delivered right to my home. We have lots <br>of food delivery here in Lisbon, but no one <br> comes even close to Omifood. Me and my <br> family are so in love!"</em>
      <p><div style="display:flex;align-items: center;"><img src="resources/css/img/customer-2.jpg" style="border-radius: 15px; height: 40px;" alt=""> Joana Silva</div></p>
      </div>
      <div><em>"I was looking for a quick and easy food <br> delivery service in San Franciso. I tried a lot <br> of them and ended up with Omnifood. Best food delivery service in the Bay Area.<br> Keep up the great work!"</em>
      <p><div style="display:flex;align-items: center;"><img src="resources/css/img/customer-3.jpg" style="border-radius: 15px; height: 40px;" alt="">Milton Chapman</div></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code i hope it will work if it helps mark it correct or add comments

```
<p><img src="imagename" alt="alt text" style="float: left">Text here</p>
```